# Evaluated Bash expression within npm install command

Tags: bash, loops, npm, expression

I want to install a list of packages from a simple text file (yes, package.json is what this was designed for)

my first approach was this:

`npm i $(cat builder-dev-packages.txt) -g`
similar to this: `docker rm $(docker ps -a -f status=exited -q)`

But I'm still getting that command evaluated as an invalid tag name.

`npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME ": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.`

Do I need to run through my npm command with a while loop instead of evaluating the output of a `cat` statement? This script still provides the same error for each line in the txt file.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='./builder/builder-dev-packages.txt'
echo Start
while read p; do 
    npm i $p --dry-run
done < $filename
```

Here is my .txt file:

```
atob
colors
comment-parser
del
gulp
gulp-autoprefixer
gulp-clean-css
gulp-concat
gulp-connect
gulp-filter
gulp-htmlmin
gulp-if
gulp-nodemon
gulp-rename
gulp-replace
gulp-rewrite-css
gulp-rtlcss
gulp-sass
gulp-sourcemaps
gulp-uglify-es
lazypipe
merge-stream
node-sass
pretty
yargs
```

Comment: share your `builder-dev-packages.txt`

Comment: My apologies, I've added the .txt to the main post.

Comment: Always quote arguments: `"$p"`, `"$filename"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install` accept a list of packages delimited by space, but you are passing it a list of packages delimited with new line, this is why you experience issues.

try the following

```sh
npm install -g $(cat builder-dev-packages.txt | tr "\n" " ")
```